# How to play DTS audio file in Sony Bluray player?

Tags: blu-ray, dlna, 5.1, ac3

I have a **Sony Bluray Player Model: BDV-E3200** (Asian).
I have 5.1ch audio files with .dts extension (DTS format) in my PC.
How to play the .dts audio files on the bluray player?

I have these methods to play: USB Drive, Network via DLNA (Serviio, UMS).
I tried using a USB drive and DLNA server, but the file wasn't detected in the player.

If I cannot directly play them, is there any alternative way such as transcoding while using DLNA or converting the dates into a compatible format while preserving the 5.1 channels?

Please help!

Comment: I bought this model recently, very sad as it doesn't play dts-hd over dlna. 
Manual says so that it wont support DTS over DLNA. 

But nothing is mentioned about USB and DTS is not playable using USB as well. 

Did you raise complain to Sony about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a .CUE file like the following then you should be able to use it to burn the tracks to a CD/DVD/BD using ImgBurn or CDRWin.

```
PERFORMER "Eagles"
TITLE "Hotel California"
FILE "Eagles - 01 - Hotel California.dts" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "Hotel California"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
FILE "Eagles - 02 - New kid in town.dts" WAVE
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "New kid in town"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
FILE "Eagles - 03 - Life in the fast lane.dts" WAVE
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "Life in the fast lane"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
```

Comment: I actually don't want to use a disk. And I also don't have a Disk Burner in my Computer. Aother solution ? using USB, DLNA or Bluetooth ?

Comment: USB and BT won't work if the player itself doesn't recognise the format. Something that transcodes and then sends over BT would work, as would some media streamer that transcodes. You can try Plex, Twonky etc. but I'm not sure whether they will help in this case.

Comment: Can you please help me with the process of burning them to a DVD Disk? 
How to create .CUE file? How to burn using that? @Karan

Comment: I've given you the format of the CUE file so just use any text editor and modify it as per your needs, then burn using ImgBurn.

Comment: You mean burn the .CUE file along with the songs, with an entry for each song? Right?

Comment: Yes, an entry for each song. Just open the CUE with ImgBurn; it'll know what to do.